# function to double size of array arbitrary number of times?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get this function to create anew array to be 2x the size of the array argument, copy the contents into the new array, and for the second half of the array, create new values by doing 2*the values in the first half of the array, then delete the original array. Repeat this process for the specified number of times, then return the new array.  I feel like I have the right algorithm down but my code isn't working.  Please help!

```
int *ArrayDynamicAllocation(int array[], int size, int number)
{
    int *new_array = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<number-1; i++)
    {
        new_array = new int[size*2];
        for(int j=0; j<size-1; j++)
        {
            new_array[j]=array[j];
            new_array[j+size]=2*array[j];
        }
        array=new_array;
        delete[] array;
        size=size*2;     
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

An example output would be if my info to put into my function was 
    int arr[2] = {0,1};
    array_size = 2;
    number = 3;
I want it to output 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 4 0 2 0 4 0 4 0 8

Comment: [Off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). `size-1` should be `size`, `number-1` should likely be `number`.

Comment: `array=new_array; delete[] array;` Methinks that isn't going to end well, neither for your following iteration nor for your final return value. Pretty sure you want those lines *reversed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *ArrayDynamicAllocation(int array[], int size, int number)
{
   int *new_array = NULL;
   int *tmp_array = new int[array.length()];
   for(int k=0; k<array.length(); k++)//Initial array copying.
       tmp_array[k] = array[k];

   for(int i=0; i<number; i++)//Array range 0 to n-1
   {
      new_array = new int[size*2];
      for(int j=0; j<size; j++)//Array range 0 to n-1
      {
         new_array[j]=tmp_array[j];
         new_array[j+size]=2*tmp_array[j];
      }
      delete[] tmp_array //Deleting old array
      size=size*2; 
      tmp_array = new int[size] //Allocating memory for next iteration
      for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
        tmp_array[k] = new_array[k];//Copying array for next iteration
  }
  delete[] tmp_array;// To free memory
  return new_array;
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I handle the case if the array is [0]?

Comment: You can validate that in first line itself if the array.length()>0 do all else return same input array as output.

Answer (score 0):

c array range from 0 to size-1
change

```
for(int i=0; i<number-1; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<=number-1; i++)
```

change

```
for(int j=0; j<size-1; j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=0; j<=size-1; j++)
```

you are deleting wrong array
change

```
array=new_array;
delete[] array;
```

to

```
delete[] array;
array=new_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 template<class T>
 void changeSize1d(T*&a, const int oldSize, const int newSize){
 if(newSize<0)return 0;
 T*temp new T[newSize];
 int number = min(oldSize, newSize);
 copy(a, a+number, temp);
 delete [] a;
 a = temp;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think this is the correct answer?