# Problems changing numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

looking for some homework help.  Not for an answer just for a nudge in the right direction.  We are given an array with some numbers, the size of the array and the number of times we are to double it.  We are to double the size, copy the same numbers over and then multiply the second halves numbers by 2.

So if the array was {0,1} with number 2. The last array would be {0,1,0,2,0,2,0,4}.

My code compiles properly and is returning some very strange number, which for the original array {0,1} and number 3 is giving me a bunch of 0's and a random 135057 in the middle.

Heres my code:

```
int *ArrayDynamicAllocation(int array[], int size, int number)
{
    for (int runs = 1;runs < number; runs++) {
        int new_size = size * 2;

        int *new_array = new int[new_size];

        for (int x = 0;x < size; x++) {
            new_array[x] = array[x];
        }

        for (int y = size+1; size < new_size; size++) {
            new_array[y] = array[y];
        }

        size = new_size;
        array = new_array;
        delete [] new_array;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: You two really need to web-conference: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059689/function-to-double-size-of-array-arbitrary-number-of-times)

Comment: `array = new_array;` `delete [] new_array;` you are assigning the pointer to the memory of the newly created `new_array` to `array` and deleting the memory.

Comment: `new_array[y] = array[y];` where there is no `array[y]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Elvisjames said in comment, `array = new_array;` means you are assigning the pointer to the memory of the newly created `new_array` to `array` and `delete [] new_array;` means you are deleting both `new_array` and `array` from the memory. Because of previous assignment, `array` is pointed to the `new_array` and deleting `new_array` means deleting `array`.

So better you delete the old array first then assign the newly created array to the old array.

In your this loop:

```
for (int y = size+1; size < new_size; size++) 
{
     new_array[y] = array[y];
}
```

As @Elvisjames said in comment, `new_array[y] = array[y];` where there is no `array[y]`

You should define your `ArrayDynamicAllocation` function as following:

```
int *ArrayDynamicAllocation(int array[], int& size, int number)
{
    for (int runs = 1;runs < number; runs++) 
    {
        int new_size = size * 2;

        int *new_array = new int[new_size];

        for (int x = 0;x < size; x++) 
        {
            new_array[x] = array[x];
            new_array[x+size]=2*array[x];
        }

        size = new_size;

        // Here you should delete the old array first then assign the newly created array to the old array.
        //array = new_array;
        //delete [] new_array;  

        delete [] array;
        array = new_array;
    }
    return array;
}
```

I've change the `int size` to `int& size` for knowing the new size.